# What is / does ld.so.preload do?

Tags: linux, unix, glibc

I stumbled upon a file called `ld.so.preload` and can't find any real usage for it. Does it have something to do with the env variable `LD_PRELOAD` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good question! Actually, */etc/ld.so.preload* replaces, in a way, *LD_PRELOAD*.

*LD_PRELOAD* is subject to severe restrictions due to a security concern: it cannot execute arbitrary *setuid* binaries because, if it could, you could substitute library routines with your own malicious code, see for instance [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130711061934/http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23) for a nice discussion. In fact, you can read in [ld.so'user manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so):

> **LD_PRELOAD**
>
> A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be loaded before all others. The items of the list can be separated by spaces or colons. This can be used to selectively override functions in other shared libraries. The libraries are searched for using the rules given under DESCRIPTION. For set-user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored, and libraries in the standard search directories are loaded only if the set-user-ID permission bit is enabled on the library file.

Instead, the file */etc/ld.so.preload* suffers from no such limitation, the idea being that, if you can read/write to the directory */etc*, you already have root credentials. Hence its use. Just keep in mind that you *may* use */etc/ld.so.preload* even though you do not seem to have one at first: it is nothing but a feature of *glibc*, hence of all Linux distros (but not, to the best of my knowledge, of Unix flavors), thus you can create it and put into it the name of whichever setuid library in **any** Linux distro, and it will work.

Comment: A significant difference is that `LD_PRELOAD`, being in the environment, affects only that process.  `/etc/ld.so.preload` applies to every program that's loaded using `/lib/ld-linux.so`.

Comment: @TobySpeight True, even though this is not specific to the *LD_PRELOAD* vs. */etc/ld.so.preload* alternative.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that libraries specified by LD_PRELOAD are loaded before those specified in /etc/ld.so.preload